# How can I show image file from Amazon S3 in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3

I need to show image(thumbnail) in view page using controller/action.(like: /Image/Thumbnail)
I can send image file that is stored locally by calling the method in controller.

```
// sample code
public FileResult Thumbnail()
{
    // get image
    Stream outFile = System.IO.File.Open("c:\\test.jpg", FileMode.Open);

    // send image
    return File(outFile, "image/jpeg");
}
```

How can I send image file that is stored in Amazon S3 ?

Can I use Amazon S3 URL in the above method to return image ? -->
http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/test.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIDLH65EJ6LSWERDF&Expires=1266497098&Signature=lopDEDErjNLy2uz6X6QCNlIjkpB0%3D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return a redirect result:

```
public ActionResult Thumbnail()
{
    return Redirect("http://domain.com/test.jpg");
}
```

If the url points at the image file then it will work. Of course you shouldn't present the url of this action to user but use it in some other view as `<img>` src attribute value:

```
<img src="<%= Url.Action("Thumbnail", "ControllerName") %>" />
```

Comment: -1 Returning a redirect for an image request is a bad practice. You're telling the client to make *another* request. Increased turnaround time.

Comment: @FreshCode - fair enough.  Do you know of an alternative?

Comment: @Sean, pull and cache the image from Amazon S3 and then return an ImageResult (custom type) in your action to display the image. The best solution would of course be to avoid the indirection in the first place and teach the calling application the S3 image URL.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for... 8 years after this solution... Did I missed a better one?

Answer (score 1):

Try loading the image with a WebClient:

```
WebClient wClient = new WebClient();
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(wClient.DownloadData('http://....jpg'));

return File(stream, "image/jpg");
```

Comment: Wouldn't this beat the purpose of amazon hosting if you're going to tax the bandwidth by transloading the images?

Comment: Yes, but I want to resize images on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

you can make a webrequest to get the stream

```
public FileResult Thumbnail()
    {
        // get image
        HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/test.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIDLH65EJ6LSWERDF&Expires=1266497098&Signature=lopDEDErjNLy2uz6X6QCNlIjkpB0%3D");
        WebResponse myResp = myReq.GetResponse();

        Stream outFile = myResp.GetResponseStream();

        // send image
        return File(outFile, "image/jpeg");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<YourModelImages> GetImgById(int imgId)
 {
     using var dc = DataContext();
     return await dc.YourModelImages.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == imgId);
 }


   [Route("show-img")]
   [AllowAnonymous]
   public async Task<IActionResult> ShowImg(int imgId)
   {
       var img = await _Service.GetImgById(imgId);
       if (img == null)
       {
           return NotFound();
       }

     

       var byts = await AppService.FileReadService.ReadFileAsync(img.Url);
       return File(byts, img.Url.FileContentType());
   }
```

Razor Page :

```
 @foreach (var img in Model.Files)
 {
     <div class="col-sm-3">
         <img src="@Url.Action("ShowImg", "Controller", new {imgId = img.Id})" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" />
     </div>
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**